# Findbugs error - Bug: br is null guaranteed to be dereferenced on exception path

Tags: java, eclipse, findbugs

I need to read a properties file. I am using BufferedReader and FileReader for this purpose. I am initializing BufferedReader to null before the try section and initializing in the try section. In finally, I am closing the reader. At this point, I am getting the error mentioned in the title.

The complete code is below

```
public void getPageTitleProperties() throws IOException
    {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        String lhs, rhs;
        try 
        {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("res" + File.separator + "pagetitle.properties"));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                String [] keyvalue = line.split("=");
                lhs = keyvalue[0];
                rhs = keyvalue[1];
                expectedTitles.put(lhs, rhs);
            }
        }
        catch (RuntimeException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            br.close();
        }

        System.out.println("Expected URLs and Titles");
        for (String url : expectedTitles.keySet())
        {
            System.out.println(url + ":" + expectedTitles.get(url));
        }

    }
```

The bug details are -

How can I get rid of this error? I have tried initializing BR to non-null, initializing it in the try block (which does not work as the variable cannot be resolved in the finally block :)). In some similar posts, folks have mentioned this as possible false negative. I have also referenced to - http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#NP_GUARANTEED_DEREF, but could not figure how to get rid of the bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I get rid of this error?

The problem is that if the `BufferedReader` or `FileReader` constructor throws an exception, `br` will be null but you're still unconditionally calling `br.close()`. Check whether `br` is null before you close it in the finally block:

```
finally {
    if (br != null) {
        br.close();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, assign it *before* the `try` block:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(...);
try {
    ...
} catch (...) {
    ...
} finally {
    br.close(); // br will definitely not be null
}
```

Or even better in Java 7, use a try-with-resources statement:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(...)) {
    ...
} catch (...) {
    ...
}
```

Note that currently your `catch` blocks are dumping the error but then continuing as if nothing's happened - whereas I'd *expect* the exception to be propagated to the caller. What do you *want* to happen if the file can't be read? (With the second and third changes I've suggested, you'd still be swallowing exceptions for actual reading, but not on opening the file.)

Comment: when Jon Skeet posted an answer, nobody else dare to post new answer

Comment: Sorry. But none of the suggested approaches are getting the bug out of way and still giving the same error. If I have JDK 7.0, does that make any difference?

Comment: @Sumod: All of those answers *really* should fix the problem. The last approach (try-with-resources) is the cleanest, so I suggest you focus on that one. Edit your question with a new section showing your code there, and the exact error you're getting (with the precise code you're showing, not some other code which includes bits you haven't shown).

Comment: My apologies. Thanks a lot for the help. I used the approach of assigning br before the try block. For the approach to work, i.e. for the error to go away, I had to clean the error console, clean the project and then run FB again. This is weird, as I thought Eclipse would do a clean and rebuild automatically. I wish I could use the try with resources approach, but unfortunately the machine on which I want to deploy this has to use JDK 6.